# Keyboard taking FOREVER to popup on iPhone app while Debugging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, keyboard

In my app which is very basic right now (2 nested TableView menus and a single prebuilt View) my prebuilt View that contains 2 labels, 2 textfields and 1 button acts very strangely.
If I run in debug mode and click on one of the textfields it takes approximately 10-15 seconds before the keyboard pops up and nothing else works while waiting for it.
If I run the Leaks Performance Tool the app runs very snappy with no problem though.

Anyone seen this before?  Any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: I assume in release mode it works faster for you? The keyboard isn't always permenantly loaded in memory on the older devices such as the iPhone 3G, so it's normal for your app to hang up briefly in those cases. What device are you testing on?

Comment: Testing on the original iphone right now.  Haven't tried release mode yet as I don't have an Apple Developer License yet.  Why would it work much faster in the Leak Performance Tool though?

Comment: Is it slow because you are going through the Debug target, or because you are invoking the debugger? Try one in the Debug target, but do build and run, instead of build and debug.

Comment: If you've solved the issue (err, determined it is Apple bug), care to close this question with an answer?

Comment: The problem isn't solved.  The stuff that was edited into the original question by me was unrelated to the question and I should have removed it, which I have done now.  As for the keyboard being slow, on a Build and Run it is quicker, but we're talking it takes 10 seconds to show up rather than 15, so it's still not useable.

Comment: I googled a bit and didn't find out what "prebuilt view" means. Anyway I got a similar problem some time ago when showing a table view on top of an OpenGL view (full screen). Solution was to pause OpenGl view rendering.

Comment: "prebuilt view" meaning a view built with Interface Builder not programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a hard look at the memory usage of the App.

Are you doing any thing in the background of the apps while displaying the KB?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem!  Strangely enough having tasks running in a background queue were interfering with the keyboard popping up.  This was solved by placing the following line in the viewWillAppear which caused the keyboard to pop up when the view loaded:
  [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

i think u wont set up the first responder for that textfield .

verify your first responder to textfield

sounds like u enable that textfield from somewhere else.which is lately.

confirm the delegate is conected to fileowner of textfield